# what does for_write_seq_lis do?

Tags: fortran, valgrind, fortran90

I am debugging a Fortran 90 program with valgrind. I get errors having this in the trace

```
==93929== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==93929==    at 0x7C3D4B: for__add_to_lf_table 
==93929==    by 0x8014A8: for__open_proc.
==93929==    by 0x7C7B0F: for__open_default 
==93929==    by 0x7F3648: for_write_seq_lis 
<rest of my application backtrace>
```

And I don't understand if it's my mistake or simply a quirk of the internal library. I'd like to know what these functions do, and any other relevant information.

I am compiling with ifort (IFORT) 11.1 20100806, valgrind 3.6.0 on macosx.

Edit: I was able to spot occurrences of valgrind errors when the `associated(ptr)` intrinsic is used, or when `print *` is used. In any case, I am just curious to know what those routines are responsible for. What's an lf table ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the symbols with names beginning `for_`  are defined in the run-time libraries that the program uses, probably ones provided with the Intel compiler.  I expect you figured that out for yourself Stefano.  What they do is obscure, other than the obvious: implement various operations of Fortran.

What have you done to track down the origins of the error which makes valgrind complain that you have used an uninitialised value ?  Did you try compiling with the option `-check uninit` ?  Have you tried the Intel source checker on the code ?

EDIT: Aha.  One of the peculiarities of Fortran is that between the time it is declared and the time it is first associated with a target, a pointer does not have an association status.  It is neither associated nor not associated, and calls to ASSOCIATED may produce odd results; according to the standard they should not, for example, return either `.true.` or `.false.`.  This may be the source of your problem, though the other symptoms you report do not point this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue of what the problem is. The code works fine for small cases, but as soon as I increase the size, I get a `6591 Illegal instruction` error. I have all debug options active and I get no error message whatsoever when running on a small case. I am currently looking for the turning point in size that makes it go boom.